# Gauged topological BdG systems

Tags: condensed-matter, superconductivity, topological-order

Can anyone suggest literature showing in detail that in 2+1D, a gauged $p+ip$ or a DIII BdG superconductor is a $Z_2$ gauge theory? I know this work https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0404327 , but I am primarily interested in gauged BdG systems.

Comment: Take a look at Kitaev's 2006 paper. And it also depends on what you gauge. If you gauge the Z_2 fermion parity symmetry, then by construction it will be a Z_2 gauge theory.

Comment: Thank you. I guess my question is how to gauge the Z_2 fermion parity symmetry in BdG approach? We have the product of $c^\dagger(k)c^\dagger(-k)$ in the Hamiltonian, in $k$ space. Is it obvious that $c^\dagger(k)$ and $c^\dagger(-k)$ should be multiplied by the same power of (-1) under Z_2?

Comment: Gauging should be done in the coordinate space. If you have a $c_i^\dagger c_j$ or $c_ic_j$ term, then couple them to $\sigma^z_{ij}$, which is the gauge field on the link $ij$. You will also need to add the Gauss law as a constraint on the Hilbert space.